# Nested form in Rails not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nested, associations, nested-forms

I'm using Rails 4.2 with `cocoon gem` for building nesting form. Everything is saving and displaying just fine except when I want to make new `person` through `entities` form. Goal is to make new person on the fly at the same form where i will make new entity.

Here is code:

Models:

```
class Entity < ActiveRecord::Base  
  has_many :bonds
  has_many :personas, :through => :bonds

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :bonds, allow_destroy: true, reject_if: :all_blank
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :personas, allow_destroy: false, reject_if: :all_blank
end

class Bond < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :entity
  belongs_to :persona
end

class Persona < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :bonds
  has_many :entities, :through => :bonds

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :entities
end
```

Here is my form that works, except of when i try to add new `person` to it.

/views/entities/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @entity do |f| %>

    <h3>Info:</h3>
        <%= f.label :name %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>

        <%= f.label :number %>
        <%= f.number_field :number %>

    <h3>Bonds:</h3>
    <div id="bonds">
      <%= f.fields_for :bonds do |ff| %>
      <%= render 'bond_fields', :f => ff %>
      <% end %>
      <div class="links">
        <%= link_to_add_association 'add bond', f, :bonds %>
      </div>
    </div>

      <%= f.submit %>
  <% end %>
```

/entities/_bond_fields.html.erb

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
    <%= f.label "Persona: " %>
    <div class="persona">
      <div class="persona_from_list">
      <%= f.association :persona, :collection => Persona.order(:name), :prompt => 'Choose an existing owner' %>
      </div>
      <%= link_to_add_association "add a new person as owner", f, :persona %>
    </div>

    <%= f.label "how much: " %>
    <%= f.number_field :how_much %>

    <%= f.label "percent: " %>
    <%= f.number_field :percent %>

  <%= link_to_remove_association "remove bond", f %>
</div>
```

/entities/_persona_fields.html.erb

```
  <div class='nested-fields'>
      <%= f.label "Name: " %>
      <%= f.text_field :name %> 

      <%= f.label "Code: " %>
      <%= f.text_field :p_code %>

      <%= link_to_remove_association "chose from list", f %>
  </div>
```

I have added strong params everywhere so probably that's not the problem. Maybe you can help I have no ideas what is wrong!

Here is my params in /entities_controller

```
params.require(:entity).permit(:name, :number, :address, :registered_at, 
:bonds_attributes => [:id, :persona_id, :entity_id, :percent, :date, :_destroy, 
:personas_attributes => [:id, :name, :p_kods, :living ] ], 
:personas_attributes => [:id, :name, :p_kods, :living ] )
```

Thanks anyways...

Comment: Strong params could still be the problem, but it's impossible to say unless you show your params methods to us.

Comment: Do you have `:personas_attributes => [ ... ]` in your `entities_controller` strong params?

Comment: yes i have `:personas_attributes` in entities_controller. I added entire strong params to my question. you can take a look.

Answer (score 0):

After carefully reading server log, I saw there was `Unpermitted parameter: persona_attributes`.

So solution was just to change from `personas_attributes` to `persona_attributes` in `EntitiesController`. Strange but rails was passing params for Persona singular while I writed in plural.

Hope it will help others too...